# Calling main function with arguments that are defined as #define

Tags: c

i am currently trying to get arguments from the command line to my main function in c. my program is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BANK1 (0X00100)
#define BANK2 (0x11010)
.
.
#define BANKN (0xNNNNN)
int write_to_bank(int bank, int value);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int a,v;
a=strtol(argv[2],NULL,0);
v=strtol(argv[3],NULL,0);
write_to_bank(a,v);

}

int write_to_bank(int bank, int value){
// some relevant code
}
```

if i pass the arguments as follows the integers are correctly parsed to the function

```
./main 0x00100 0x20
```

but when i try to pass the arguments to my main function in the following way i am not actually parsing the right bank value

```
./main BANK1 0x30
```

Is there any way i could pass the definition as an argument to my main functuion where c automatically translates the definition to the corresponding value and parses to the function argument.

Comment: You can't,`BANK1` is replaced by `(0x00100)` before source code is compiled (preprocessed). `BANK1` exist only within that file.

Comment: Why it this tagged as [tag:C++]?

Comment: sorry this is my first question in the forum added c++ accidentally

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The C Preprocessor is not a part of the compiler, but is a separate
>   step in the compilation process. In simple terms, a C Preprocessor is
>   just a text substitution tool and it instructs the compiler to do
>   required pre-processing before the actual compilation. Read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm)

This means that when you have your .exe file there is no reference to `BANK1 - BANK2` and so on.
They are sobstituted before compilation phase with their values. In fact:

> `#define` Substitutes a preprocessor macro.

When you give in input `BANK1` that is just a string!

---

### EXAMPLE:

If you try this example, you can understand how preprocessor works. When you compile your code it substitute `__TIME__` constant with the current time, and whenever you'll execute your code it'll print the time when you compiled:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Time :%s\n", __TIME__ );

    getchar();
}
```

For more read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the way preprocessor definitions work: they are a completely compile-time construct. By the time the compiler finishes the translation (in fact, by the time the compiler *starts* the translation) the definitions such as `BANK1` and `BANK2` are gone irretrievably.

If you would like to use symbolic names for numbers, you need to build this functionality yourself: add a check for `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` to be a C string containing `BANK1` or `BANK2` using `strcmp`, then either call `strtol` or use a pre-defined constant:

```
#define STR(X) #X
...
int parse(const char* str) {
    if (strcmp(str, STR(BANK1)) == 0) {
        return BANK1;
    }
    if (strcmp(str, STR(BANK2)) == 0) {
        return BANK2;
    }
    return strtol(str, NULL, 0);
}
```

**Note:** In case you are curious of how `STR(X)` works, look up [*stringizing operator*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score -1):

When you call

```
./main BANK1 0x30
```

`BANK1` is a string. In your code `BANK1` is a integer. So you have to map it. Read the argument as a string and search for it in a map [like here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/)

Comment: I am sing c the link you have given me seems to be a c++ link.

Comment: @J.W. BANK1 is not an integer. BANK1 has been sobstituted by preprocessor.

Comment: Yeah i know, but the thing he needs to know is that `BANK1` as paramter given to application is not the same like in his code `BANK1`. i admit thats not 100% correctly said. Just wanted to make it simple. Anyways he needs to map the values himself

Comment: @J.W. If you pass in input the name of a variable it will works? NO. Maybe you make it too simple and in your answer is written something false!